# Partition list at repeated element

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a long flat list that needs to be partitioned.  The list is formatted so the "header" is repeated, followed by the values.  Essentially, it looks something like this:

```
list={a,a,1,2,3,b,b,5,6,c,c,1,5,a,a,7,8,9,1}
```

I am looking for an output of:

```
{{a,1,2,3},{b,5,6},{c,1,5},{a,7,8,9,1}}
```

The output above would then let me create the association list I need.

Obviously `Partition` won't work because the sublists are of different lengths. I have looked at various ways to identify where the repeated "header" data is, but that doesn't help with the splits.

Comment: What is the header data? Is it symbols? Or a string? Or also numbers?

Comment: In the actual data, all items would be treated as strings

Comment: Should the list be split _any_ duplicate or are there some known header strings?

Comment: All headers will repeat and none of the following values will repeat.  There is a chance that sets will have the same headers.  Essentially, anytime a value is equal to the value before it, it can be used as the split point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Join[Most /@ Rest @ Most @ #, {Last @ #}] & @ Split[list, UnsameQ]
```

> {{a, 1, 2, 3}, {b, 5, 6}, {c, 1, 5}, {a, 7, 8, 9, 1}}

You can also use use `Split` twice and reorganize the result:

```
Rest /@ Flatten /@ Split[Split[list], Length @ #2 == 1 &]
```

> {{a, 1, 2, 3}, {b, 5, 6}, {c, 1, 5}, {a, 7, 8, 9, 1}}

And yet an alternative way:

```
Take[list, {#, #2 - 2}] & @@@ 
 Partition[Last /@ SequencePosition[list, {a_, a_}], 2, 1, 1, {Length[list] + 2}]
```

> {{a, 1, 2, 3}, {b, 5, 6}, {c, 1, 5}, {a, 7, 8, 9, 1}}

Comment: That seems to have done it.  Let me dig into the final output to see if there is any trickery going on.

Comment: Okay, I think I am following.  Normally `Split` puts all the same repeated elements together, but by specifying that `UnsameQ` you are grouping things that are dissimilar.  That makes sense.  Then by mapping `Most` you are dropping the last element of each sublist.  I am not quite sure I understand what you are doing with the the `Replace` all and `SlotSequence`.  Obviously the first list will be invalid, but couldn't you just use `Rest[Most /@ Split[list, UnsameQ]]`

Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: @kickert, the original answer was incorrect. Fixed now. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: Right or wrong, all your solutions got me where I needed to be.

Answer (score 8):

```
SequenceSplit[list, {a_, a_, x:_Integer ..} -> {a,x}]
```

> {{a, 1, 2, 3}, {b, 5, 6}, {c, 1, 5}, {a, 7, 8, 9, 1}}

Answer (score 1):

```
Split[
   DeleteAdjacentDuplicates[list, MatchQ[#1, _Symbol] && MatchQ[#2, _Symbol] &], 
IntegerQ[#2] &]
```

{{a, 1, 2, 3}, {b, 5, 6}, {c, 1, 5}, {a, 7, 8, 9, 1}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list={a,a,1,2,3,b,b,5,6,c,c,1,5,a,a,7,8,9,1};

Split[list, Head[#1] == Symbol || Head[#2] == Integer &] // Map[Rest]
```

> {{a, 1, 2, 3}, {b, 5, 6}, {c, 1, 5}, {a, 7, 8, 9, 1}}